# Removing extra column line at the end of a table while using longtable in LaTeX

Tags: longtable

Can somebody help how to remove the extra lines marked in red while using longtable command? It appears at the end of every table.

here is how I started:

```
begin{longtable}{|c|c|p{0.55\linewidth}|}
```

everything is perfect except the extra lines.

Thank you very much

[image: extra line]

Comment: Welcome ... Have you compiled twice?

Comment: Please add a compete minimal working example that can be used to reproduce your problem. Wild guess: does your longtable and with //&?

Comment: Those lines are not caused by `longtable` as such but with content in them. For proof try: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|p{0.55\linewidth}|}
    \hline
1. column & 2. Column   & some longer text split ove more lines

                          \lipsum[66]  \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}`. Since content of your table is unknown, we can't help you. BTW, showed table cannot be produced with column specifiers as you show to us.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses, and sorry for not posting the complete info.
I solved my problem. It was due to the \label{table xx} which I included at the end after \hline command. I thought it is similar to using \being {tabular}.
When I deleted that line, the extra lines got removed